# Orbeon FormBuilder Embedding

Tags: forms, orbeon

How do i embed Orbeon form builder in a non java webapp, (Plain Javascript) as well as customising its look (CSS). I am currently embedding it using an iframe but it doesn't seem to be a very good option. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding Form Builder with the [JavaScript embedding API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/javascript-api) isn't supported yet. At this point, you can only embed Form Builder with the [Java embedding API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/java-api).

There is no fondamental reason why this couldn't possible from the JavaScript API; it is just a question of issues that still need to be ironed out (for more on this, see issue [#4483](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4483)). So, as I write this, if you can't use the Java embedding API, you're correct and the only way to do this is to use an iframe.